# Naive Problem: Receiving same data from all four different links

Tags: python, pandas

```
import pandas as pd
df31_12_r1 = pd.read_html('https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html#r1')[0]

df31_12_r2 = pd.read_html('https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html#r2')[0]

df31_12_r3 = pd.read_html('https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html#r3')[0]

df31_12_r4 = pd.read_html('https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html#r4')[0]
```

The result displayed is the same from all the data frame, however it should be different:
One result is displayed (other three are similar):

```
Unit    Power   Down    Reason or Comment   Change in report (*)    Number of Scrams (#)
0   Beaver Valley 1 100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
1   Beaver Valley 2 100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
2   Calvert Cliffs 1    100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
3   Calvert Cliffs 2    100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
4   FitzPatrick 100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
5   Ginna   100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
6   Hope Creek 1    0   10/10/2004  REFUELING OUTAGE    NaN NaN
7   Indian Point 2  100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
8   Indian Point 3  100 NaN NaN NaN NaN
9   Limerick 1  99  NaN REDUCED POWER DUE TO FEEDWATER FLOW CONCERNS    NaN NaN
```

How we can get exact data to each link instead, link pulling only top CSV file data from the webpage?
Thank you in advance for help!

Comment: The same name is used for all DataFrames. Changing the last number to match the url might solve your problem.

Comment: No, no that is a typo here not in python notebooks, let me correct it.

Answer (score 3):

All tables are in one html page, so is possible create list of DataFrames `dfs` and then select by index:

```
url = 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)


df1 = dfs[0]
df2 = dfs[1]
df3 = dfs[2]
df4 = dfs[3]

print (df1.head())
print (df2.head())
print (df3.head())
print (df4.head())
```

If need one DataFrame with join list of DataFrames `dfs` add [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.concat.html):

```
url = 'https://www.nrc.gov/reading-rm/doc-collections/event-status/reactor-status/2004/20041231ps.html'
dfs = pd.read_html(url)

df = pd.concat(dfs, ignore_index=True)
```